# App won't open keep getting the below error in LogCat

Tags: java, android

Fatal Exception Error in LogCat.

Have no errors when running App but won't run in emulator.
App won't open "App has stopped" "Open Again" and same error happens.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Colin

LogCat:

```
"2019-06-26 21:29:28.339 7103-7103/com.example.fbgooglelogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fbgooglelogin, PID: 7103
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fbgooglelogin/com.wapptech.fbgooglelogin.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.fbgooglelogin-WHX7XQ3Rd_hbREQiANU6cw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.fbgooglelogin-WHX7XQ3Rd_hbREQiANU6cw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.wapptech.fbgooglelogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-06-26 21:29:28.339 7103-7103/com.example.fbgooglelogin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
"
```

Dependancies all up to date.
In fact is there any way that these can be set to auto update? what a pain - when I change one it causes conflicts with another.

Comment: The error indicates that there is a problem in the xml layout for your MainActivity, can you share the xml here?

Comment: post code of your activity_main.xml here.

Comment: Have you included the correct version of the support library in your gradle build config?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your TextInputLayout Widget in mainActivity xml,Line 20.
share that widget code lines please.

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks, here is the code for TextInputLayout Widget in MainActivity xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wapptech.fbgooglelogin.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">



        <!-- Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Login"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fb"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#416BC1"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="FaceBook Login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/google"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#cf4333"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Google Login"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGN UP"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="@color/ColorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```